# Is there a macOS alternative to delaycut or eac3to?

Tags: macos, audio, software-recommendation, software

I'm looking to edit some audio tracks for movies without reencoding them.

I've searched online, and apparently [delaycut](https://www.videohelp.com/software/delaycut) and [eac3to](https://www.videohelp.com/software/eac3to) would be good for what I'm aiming to do (according to [an Original Trilogy forum post](http://originaltrilogy.com/topic/How-do-I-cut-a-section-of-an-AC3-audio-file-without-re-encoding/id/17633)).  The problem is that that they're both Windows-exclusive applications.  A possible alternative might be [Audio Cutter](https://www.ifunia.com/audio-cutter-mac.html), but some of the reviews on the App Store have me hesitant to pay for it.

Can anyone suggest a macOS application that can do what I want to do?  (I'd prefer something free, but if there's no free option, that's fine.)

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is extract segments of audio from an audio file and save them to files, then I suggest Audacity.

It is open sourced, cross platform, and probably can do what you need with ease.

Comment: Can I do this in Audacity without having to reencode the new file(s)?  I'm looking to not lose any quality in the process.

Comment: @1dareu2mov3  please run me through precisely what you intend to do.  What is the format of the initial material?  Please be specific, including what the final format of the segmented audio clips needs to be.

Comment: There is a program called [Video Editor ][1] that may do what you want. It's a commercial package but they offer a free trial. www.iskysoft.com/filmora-video-editor-mac.html